# Git to auto-detect the system proxy settings

Tags: git, proxy

I am often changing places that have different proxy settings, or simply changing from WiFi to cable connection with a different proxy.

As I am using OsX, it is easy to switch from a network configuration to another. But git has its own setting in the *.gitconfig* file and I am tired modifying that file every time.

Is there a way to pass the proxy (maybe from a system variable?) to the *.gitconfig* file, or have a setting such as *auto-detect*, *system-proxy* or similar?

Comment: Any progress since 2015?

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same situation, it's a pity that Git does not use the system proxy settings on OS X. To make this easier, I've created a couple of Bash functions that allow me to enable/disable the proxy configuration for tools like ssh, npm and the proxy environment variables.

You can see the code (as part of my *Bash-it* fork) here: https://github.com/nwinkler/bash-it/blob/master/plugins/available/proxy.plugin.bash

Here's how it works:

- My bash profile contains variables like `BASH_IT_HTTP_PROXY`.
- I have defined some functions including `enable_proxy` and `disable_proxy` that set or unset the environment variables when called. In addition to that, they update my `~/.npmrc` file and some other locations.

When working from the office (where I have to use a proxy), I simply call `enable_proxy`, and when working from home, I call `disable_proxy`.

A similar set of functionality could be implemented as single scripts instead of functions, but the *Bash-it* framework has a really nice way of defining things like this. It works really well, and I never have to fiddle with environment variables manually.