# Location Specific Github Proxy

Tags: github, networking, proxy, location

I have a work laptop that resides between a painful corporate proxy during the day. When I'm at home, I don't have to worry about a proxy unless I VPN in.

Is there a way to set-up an automatic github proxy, such that if I'm at work it'll use the corporate proxy, and if I'm at home, it'll remove proxy settings?

Or perhaps a way that attempt 1 is made with a proxy, and attempt 2 is made without?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can set it manually through pre-defined scripts/functions, as described here:

- See [nwinkler/bash-it/plugins/available/proxy.plugin.bash](https://github.com/nwinkler/bash-it/blob/e56b789dcb87d47d2e0676c45dd39b72e4066e49/plugins/available/proxy.plugin.bash)
- "When working from the office (where I have to use a proxy), I simply call `enable_proxy`, and when working from home, I call `disable_proxy`", as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736538/6309).

You could wrap this in a test, which tries a curl without and then with HTTP(S)_PROXY variable, in order to see which call is successful.
On Linux, that test could be part of your `.bashrc`, which would allow any new shell session to open itself with the right settings set or not.